# Denied permissions to download file from Dropbox API in Python

Tags: python, permissions, dropbox

I'm trying to download a CSV file from Dropbox using their library in Python, but I'm having quite the issue trying to get the permissions needed to be able to actually get it into the computer.

The error message that I'm getting in any case is this:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'my_directory'

So I've tried the only two solutions I'm finding as I investigate: 1) change the mode of the directory to `'0o777'` using `os.chmod()`, and 2) running things as an admin. But even with both, I'm still not getting rights to write the file to my local computer. It might also be worth noting that the name of the file and the directory I'm trying to write it to do not have the same name.

```
import os
import dropbox

local_dir = 'absolute_path_to_directory'

os.chmod(local_dir, 0o777)
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('my_token_here')
dbx.files_download_to_file(local_dir, 'path_to_file_in_dropbox')
```

I would think that running this kind of program as an administrator and having changed the directory permissions, I would have permissions to actually download the file to it. But I'm still getting the PermissionError I noted above.

Any help or insight into what might be causing the issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarity could you state the OS and python version you are using?

Comment: My python is version 3.6.4. I'm not sure about my OS module but I'm sure it's above version 3.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [chmod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod) you can only set the read-only flag all other bits are ignored. However, this might not be the problem.

Looking at the [dropbox forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Downloading-a-file-from-using-the-Python-Dropbox-API/m-p/230459#M16826), it looks like you might be missing a '/' along with the filename, and not just the directory.

```
dbx.files_download_to_file(j, '/'+ j)
```

According to [Greg](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Error-downloading-files-from-dropbox-API/m-p/259520#M15097)

> You do need to use the full path when specifying the file you want to download. Using files_list_folder and files_list_folder_continue will give you every entry, and you can get the full path from the returned (File)Metadata.path_lower. (I.e., use `entry.path_lower` instead of `'/'+entry.name`.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I appreciate the insight into `os.chmod`, and I also already had taken care of the '/' in the Dropbox filepath. I took Greg's advice and tried using the `path_lower` info of the file I'm looking to pull in (which appears to just be a version of the path in lowercase), but to no avail. I'm still hitting the permissions issue.